# Не работает бот на Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, heroku

столкнулся с проблемой установки бота на сервер. все проходит гладко до момента запуска.
бот написан на Long Polling. Вылезает ошибка H14

```
Procfile: worker: python3 main.py
```

вот мой лог:

```
2020-05-12T23:01:46.750934+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user anton.04291@gmail.com
2020-05-12T23:01:46.750934+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user anton.04291@gmail.com
2020-05-12T23:01:45.915416+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user anton.04291@gmail.com
2020-05-12T23:01:45.915416+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user anton.04291@gmail.com
2020-05-12T23:04:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user anton.04291@gmail.com
2020-05-12T23:04:39.225953+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 825af50d by user anton.04291@gmail.com
2020-05-12T23:04:39.225953+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user anton.04291@gmail.com
2020-05-12T23:04:47.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-12T23:05:19.781787+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=cinemabot-teleapi.herokuapp.com request_id=acc93736-0b55-403c-9206-484a9bef4711 fwd="94.233.251.103" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Вы пробовали установить необходимое количество `dyno` при помощи `heroku ps:scale web=1`?

Comment: А это разве ошибка? Бот на поллинге, веб процессов нет.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что ошибка в самом Procfile. У меня в Procfile указано:

```
worker: python main.py
```

Подробная информация о Procfile на оф.сайте, по ссылке: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile